# Google Sheets - dynamic lookup sum

Tags: google-sheets

I have a vertical list of points and several horizontal sheets of data. I want to get a sum of the data from each of those sheets, multiply them by value of their header key, and get a sum of each row of data.

[image]

For row 2 I want the total to be 1,011 (3 x 123 = 369, 2 x 321 = 642, 369 + 642 ==  1,011) where it looks up the header of aaa and bbb, gets their point value, and multiplies it by their row value. I'm sure I can hack it and get the result but I'd like to get an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a straightforward SUMPRODUCT formula.

```
=sumproduct((A3:A4=D1:E1)*(B3:B4)*(D2:E2))
```

[image]

[Sample Google-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BA50AM3jRXM6izEkTZ-0uehhopm71roxxnB3EQ_j7sY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks! I ended tweaking it a little bit `=sumproduct(($A$3:$A$4=D$1:E$1)*($B$3:$B$4)*(D3:E3))` but this will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B*iferror(hlookup(A:A,D1:E2,2,false),0))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B*iferror(hlookup(A:A,1:2,2,false),0))
```

[image]